# Text widget is not working with page builder by site origion plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit the text widget in my page. But I am not able to edit the text in that. Because it is blank screen. I checked my console it is showing

> Uncaught Error: Missing options.syncContainer(…)

I am using latest version of WordPress and pagebuilder by siteorigion plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks there's a problem with the plugin Page Builder by SiteOrigin because of Wordpress 4.8.1. Waiting for plugin update as well
'I' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]